# Selecte and retrieve file path to image using dialog box

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm expanding Wordpress to function more like a CMS. This includes relating image to a post.

Currently I have a text field where I paste an image path.
Now I want to click a button which opens a dialog box, then I navigate to the right folder and select a file to "open" (from server side).

The file path is returned.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of [Post Thumbnails?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). It sounds like you're duplicating what they do.

Add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` to the `functions.php` file of your current theme.

If you don't have a file named `functions.php` in your theme, create one, and put this in it:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
?>
```

if that still does not do what you want you might look at [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: +1 for add_theme_support, but as far as i know 'post-thumbnails' is supported in lastest version of wordpress.

Comment: Yes, it's in there in 2.9.2 -- and it's awesome! But the posting interface to add post thumbnails to posts or pages does not appear unless you activate it in `functions.php`. I think it was decided not to show it unless the theme claims to use it. If more themes supported it, I think more people would use it!

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that this morning: http://wpengineer.com/new-feature-in-wordpress-2-9-the_post_image/. But as Artlung says, it's not visible in WP by default. I will see if I can customize this even further. E.g. one cannot see what imaeg is related, and it's also placed in the side bar. Thanks!